# How to use logging module in python with different timestamp?

Tags: python, logging

My location is behind 3 hours from the server location and I want to make my log time the same with my local time without changing the my servers' settings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python logging: How to set time to GMT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321160/python-logging-how-to-set-time-to-gmt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer would be

```
import logging
import time

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')
logging.warning('server time')

logging.Formatter.converter = lambda self, current: time.localtime(current-3600*3)

logging.warning('time at your zone')
```

The `time.localtime` is server time. and then I gave bias -3600*3 (or + is possible).