# How to keep UTC time in logging while changing the TIME_ZONE settings?

Tags: python, django, timezone, utc

I set the time zone in the `settings.py` file of my django project:

`TIME_ZONE = 'US/Eastern'`

and now my logs contain US/Eastern times.

I would like to keep an UTC time in my logs. Is that possible?

Comment: Django just uses Python logging, so search for that. This looks like a simple approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8334378/2395796.

Comment: It does not seem like you can change it in a logging dictconfig. A formatter accepts only format and datefmt and I do not see a way to set the class for the Formatter.

Comment: I think you can achieve this with the key `()`; see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#user-defined-objects).

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Thanks, that did the trick. You can create an answer if you want so that I can accept it.

Comment: I think you can set `TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Django uses Python's logging facilities, so there shouldn't be anything Django-specific here.

According to [the logging documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter.formatTime), setting `logging.Formatter.converter = time.gmtime` should make all logs output in UTC.

Alternatively, you can make your own `Formatter` class to use UTC:

```
class UtcFormatter(logging.Formatter): 
    converter = time.gmtime
```

And then configure it using the `()` key (documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#user-defined-objects)) in the dictconfig:

```
LOGGING = {
    'formatters': {
        'utc': { 
            '()': 'my.package.UtcFormatter',
            'format': '...',
            'datefmt': '...',
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems that this is partially working. I applied this formatter to a handler which deals with stdout logging, and what happens is that, log call that I do throughout the code, are on UTC, but the logs of HTTP requests that are registered by Django, are still on my timezone. Have any clue? Thanks for this answer anyway.

Comment: I tried both, but the thing here is that these options seems to have no interaction with Django Request logger, which is the one who registers the request.
For the other logger that I have, your approaches work perfectly, with time in UTC, but the logs generated for each request (Django), timestamps still are on my timezone.
I'm looking for a way to customize it. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/utils/log/

Comment: @ivanleoncz: Sorry, I'm not sure offhand. I haven't heard of this before so I suspect it has something to do with your configuration. Try posting a new question where you can give more details and a minimal example.